# Java HashMap not working in Processing

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, processing

I'm trying to do a simple Java HashMap in Processing.

I can't see anything wrong but I'm still getting an error.

```
//for hashmap (dictionary)
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

//scales
HashMap<String,String> scalesList = new HashMap<String,String>();
scalesList.put("C Maj","cmaj.xml");
```

[These are the errors I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2436.png)

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Luke

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that this shouldn't be your whole sketch, but it should include all the code we need to copy and paste it onto our own machines to repeat the problem.

Comment: you should post your code in your question rather than use an external link.  Just add 4 spaces to start each line.

Comment: @PeterLawrey This isn't Java. It's Processing. Note the tags.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I noted the first tag is `[java]`, should this be removed?

Comment: @PeterLawrey It's complicated. Processing uses a lot of Java syntax, and in fact it's written in Java. But not all Java rules apply to Processing. It can be confusing for novice Processing developers, as well as experienced Java devs. I don't know what the solution is for Stack Overflow tags. Take a look at the [tag:processing] tag to see how many are also tagged with Java. Might even be worth a meta discussion.

Comment: Apologies for not using an MCVE, I'm new to asking questions on here, I'll keep it in mind for the future. 

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have declarations outside of methods, not statements:

```
HashMap<String, String> sl = new HashMap<String, String>(); //this is a declaration
sl.put("C Maj", "cmaj.xml"); //this is a statement, it needs to be inside a method!
```

Instead, you have to put statements inside methods, like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> sl = new HashMap<String, String>();

void setup(){
   size(500, 500);
   sl.put("C Maj", "cmaj.xml");
}
```

Comment: Sorted straight away. Thanks very much! Much appreciated.

Comment: @PeterLawrey This is Processing, not Java. The methods and fields are inside a **sketch**, not necessarily a class.

Comment: @user3277329 No problem. In the future you really should try to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, not a picture of your code and error. If you edit your post to include an MCVE, you'll probably get fewer downvotes and close-votes.

Comment: Does processing support the `{ }` initialiser blocks?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yeah it does. In fact, since Processing "compiles" to Java, it supports pretty much everything that Java does. It just eliminates a lot of the boilerplate needed for things like classes and main methods and events and whatnot. However, most Processing code uses the `setup()` function for things like this, so I'm not sure an initializer block is the way to go here.